# How to get share count for a 'post' using fb api feed operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using `Ruby 2.1.1`, `rails 4` and `Koala` gem to post pictures and comment on facebook using feed method of `Koala` gem. So I get response from FB API with post id.

Now I want to fetch statistics corresponding to post which was posted previously.

I am able to fetch likes and comments for that post, but unable to get shared count. So can anyone suggest me that how can  I get number of shared count for that post ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the endpoint

```
/{object-id}/sharedposts
```

at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/sharedposts